# Why this declaration line does not give any error

Tags: java

```
int [           ] a;
```

What is happening in this line can anybody describe. It has spaces between [].

Comment: So it has spaces. Any two tokens can have arbitrary whitespace between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a reference to an array which is presently null, and therefore of undefined size.

This is correct syntax. The spaces in between square brackets are not relevant.

Here is some proper further usage:

```
int [] a = new int[10];
```